# Laravel не открывает public

Tags: laravel

Развернул Laravel на сервере, как заставить открываться как обычный сайт ?

Comment: уточни чтоты видишь  по запросу ip, имени сайта?
какой используешь сервер: apache / nginx

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment

Comment: скажи свой ip. Мы тебя вычислим, подключимся и всё поправим.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно настроить Ваш сервер, чтоб он смотрел на папку public, а не на целый проект Laravel